# Swift array move function doesn't behave as you would expect - why?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

Recently Swift has a new method called move for Arrays.  We can use it to tie in with Swiftui list drag and drop list moves.  My challenge is that I don't understand how it works standalone and the docs in Apple are sparse about this.  Here's a weird behavior I've noticed when I just play with this function.

```
var array = ["a", "b" ,"c", "d"]
print("before \(array)\n")
array = ["a", "b" ,"c", "d"]
array.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: 2), toOffset: 1)
print("after 2 -> 1 \(array)")
        
array = ["a", "b" ,"c", "d"]
array.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: 1), toOffset: 2)
print("after 1 -> 2 \(array)")

array = ["a", "b" ,"c", "d"]
array.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: 2), toOffset: 2)
print("after 2 -> 2 \(array)")
```

Results are:

```
after 2 -> 1 ["a", "c", "b", "d"]

after 1 -> 2 ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

after 2 -> 2 ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

I'm super confused about the 1->2 result ... how's that not change the array! It should be the same as the 2->1 shouldn't it?

Please help me understand.

Comment: Seems to work as expected the first swaps b and c. The second swaps them back and the third doesn’t do anything. What are you expecting?

Comment: See workingdgo's answer. Prove that it is right to yourself by using 0 instead of 1. The offset can be up to 4, not 3.

Comment: @loremipsum I reset to a b c d before all the moves operations ... I expected the 1-> 2 and 2->1 be the same exact end result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my understanding of the `move` operation is:

Moves all the elements at the specified offsets to the specified destination offset, preserving ordering.

The move is to `just before destination`, so the results you get are correct.

Comment: I think what I was missing in my understanding is toOffset is not newIndex and the fact that the item moves to "just before destination".  That explains it. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder, why didn't Apple just introduce something like `move(fromIndex, toIndex)`? Why do we need `IndexSet`?

Comment: @KyryloZapylaiev so that you can move multiple elements at once

Answer (score 9):

I spent some time making ASCII art diagrams, so let's not put that time to waste.

Conceptually, I think of it as:

- index points to the actual element
- offset is the number of spaces travelled from the start of the array; essentially pointing at the gap between the elements

Thus, the algorithm is to:

- get the item at specified index
- determine the target offset (based on the array as it stands)
- move that item into that offset

So, with your use cases:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"]: moving from index 2 to offset 1: ["a", "c", "b", "d"]

|a|b|c|d| |a|b|c|d|
     v      ^
     |      |
     +------+

["a", "b", "c", "d"]: moving from index 1 to offset 2: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

|a|b|c|d| |a|b|c|d|
   v          ^
   |          |
   +----------+

["a", "b", "c", "d"]: moving from index 2 to offset 2: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

|a|b|c|d| |a|b|c|d|
     v        ^
     |        |
     +--------+
```

As you can see, nominating an offset that would place the element adjacent to itself would result in no apparent change to the array.